# Oracle - Using an Alias in the fist parameter of the REGEX_COUNT Function

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Is it possible to use an alias as the first parameter in a REGEXP_COUNT function instead of the actual field name. For example I used the following:

```
SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name as fullname,
       REGEXP_COUNT(fullname, 'o', 1, 'i') AS total
FROM BROKERS
```

I keep receiving an error "invalid identifier" which made me think that I would have to call it as one field instead of calling the concatenated "fullname"

Comment: No.  In Oracle it is not possible to re-use a column alias in the `select` where it is defined.  This is true of almost all databases.  Use a subquery or CTE instead.

Comment: Gordon, how would that look with a subquery if you could show me please. Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(b.fullname, 'o', 1, 'i') AS total
  FROM (SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name as fullname
          FROM BROKERS) b;
```

Or you can just do the concatenation in the function:

```
SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name as fullname,
       REGEXP_COUNT(first_name ||' '|| last_name, 'o', 1, 'i') AS total
  FROM BROKERS
 GROUP BY first_name ||' '|| last_name;
```

If you want to select the 'fullname' and the count of it you need also a `group by`

```
SELECT b.fullname,
       REGEXP_COUNT(b.fullname, 'o', 1, 'i') AS total
  FROM (SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name as fullname
          FROM BROKERS) b
  GROUP BY b.fullname;
```